# Ridge estimator in Weka's Logistic function

Tags: weka, logistic-regression

I'm reading the article "Ridge Estimators in Logistic Regression" by le Cessie and van Houwelingen, which is cited in Weka's documentation on the logistic regression function. I have to say, my maths are shaky in this area (it's been a while). In particular, I'm trying to work out the logic behind how the ridge parameter works, and what it's main purpose is.

The authors say that ridge estimators improve parameter estimates and reduce error in future predictions (this is in the abstract). I'm not exactly sure what an "ill posed problem" is, but as I understand it, the ridge estimator is meant to be a method of regularisation for this type of problem.

What do different values of the ridge parameter in Weka's Logistic regression do to change the performance of the logistic regression? 
Does the ridge paramter involve the computation a Tikhonov Matrix that favours minimum residuals?

I'm sorry if I combined too many questions into one post. I think I understand what the ridge parameter is meant to do, but not *how* it does it.